# C# SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create simple application with GUI, where i can input **SQL Server** name and id that must be updated with this string:

```
update docs SET locked=0 WHERE ID=(id entered in GUI)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Add code already you tried!

Answer (score 7):

You could write a C# function that will perform the update:

```
public int Update(int id)
{
    string connectionString = "... put the connection string to your db here ...";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE docs SET locked = 0 WHERE ID = @id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and then you could call this function by passing it some dynamic value which you obtained from the UI:

```
int id;
if (int.TryParse(someTextBox.Text, out id))
{
    int affectedRows = Update(id);
    if (affectedRows == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No rows were updated because the database doesn't contain a matching record");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid ID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net framework uses ADO.Net for SQL connections. A simple query in ADO.Net can be executed like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Yourdatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI");
int res = 0;
try
{
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update docs SET locked=0 WHERE ID= @id");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.text);
res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}catch(Exception err){ 
MessageBox.Show(err.getMessage());
}finally{
conn.Close();
}
```

1. Change the connection string to your own connection string.
2. Change (local) to localhost\SQLEXPRESS if you're using SQL Express.
3. Change "txtid.text" to whatever statement that will get your ID for you.
4. You may also check res for finding out the number of affected rows.